# How to create a HDInsight cluster with a specific timezone using ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-rm-template

I would like to create a HDInsight cluster with a specific timezone using an ARM template.

Following the templates to create VMs, I've tried to add a `"timeZone": "Romance Standard Time"` element to:

- the `computeProfile` element
- each of the `computeProfile.roles` elements
- each of the `computeProfile.roles.*.linuxOperatingSystemProfile` elements

but none of these worked.

Answer (score 1):

According to VMSS [REST Api reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualmachinescalesets/create-or-update-a-set) there's no option to do that.

You can use script extension and a custom script to configure that

Comment: thanks for the answer. It seems that the REST api does not offer the full interface. On this discussion track [LINK](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/6602810-vm-regional-settings-and-timezone) someone indicates how to create a VM with a given timezone using a cmdlet or an ARM template. As HDI's ARM template contains an "osProfile"-like element, I thought the aforementioned suggestions could also work, but it's not the case. So it may be defined differently.

Comment: this is the funniest thing I've heard in my like ;) but jokes aside, nothing has more functionality than REST Api, this is just a different resource, for VM's there's obviously ability to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-create-or-update @FernandoLemos